# Book Title ID- Asteroid with Time Traveling Tunnel?

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

Anyone remember the name of this book?
The Nations of the world send people to investigate a hollow asteroid.  What they find is a civilization- with libraries that "teach" you.

There's a tunnel- and as you go down the tunnel- you also go through time.

No one knows who built it or what it was for.
I remember enjoying the detailed descriptions of the future and would like to read it again.

Comment: When did you read it? Do you remember anything about the cover or any of the characters? What age group did it seem to be aimed at? Any detail, no matter how small, may be able to help us help you.

Comment: This question does not have an accepted answer and should **be reopened**.

Comment: @Mithrandir - I'm intrigued what worth you think there is in mass-reopening a bunch of elderly story-ID questions that were asked *and where the OP  A) never complained that they weren't the right answer and B) Hasn't ever been seen again.*

Answer (score 11):

This sounds very much like the book Eon by Greg Bear:

Description of the Stone:

> The asteroid itself is an elongated prolate spheroid which appears to be virtually identical to Juno, a large asteroid in the main belt. It has been hollowed out along its long axis, and subdivided into seven vast cylindrical chambers. It rotates to provide artificial gravity. The chambers are terraformed, the second and third containing abandoned cities which appear to be built by humans from Earth's future.

The Way:

> A startling discovery is that the Stone is larger on the inside than outside: the seventh chamber extends beyond the end of the asteroid and appears to go on forever. When Patricia is mysteriously abducted by a strange looking human and an alien, an expedition is sent after her. They travel down the final chamber (called "the corridor" or "the Way"), where they encounter humanity's descendants.

[Wiki Eon Description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eon_%28novel%29)

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like [*Eon*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eon_%28novel%29) by [Greg Bear](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greg_Bear). The asteroid is bigger on the inside than on the outside. It was built by humans from an alternate timeline, traveled back in time, and allows some of the characters to travel in time themselves.

Comment: Sounds like a camouflaged Tardis. But then, if it is produced by time lords. :)